# How to write a Groovy class for a Java class with no line of code inside

Tags: java, groovy, spock

I have a basic Java class with one constructor having no line of code inside it.

```
public class A{

    private A() {
    }

}
```

Is there any scope for writing a unit test Groovy class corresponding to this Java Class. I tried to write a test method for constructor for the class, but it did not contribute to the coverage percentage.

Also is it possible to have a corresponding Groovy class when there is no method at all (If I don't provide a constructor; can I test for the default no argument constructor that Java provides)

Is there any significance for writing unit tests for these type of classes, other than for covering the classes.

Comment: Are the class and constructor really completely empty? Why would you write such a class in the first place? Which problem are you trying to solve? What code is there to cover if there is no code? It is hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. Before you speculate about the technical way to solve a problem, please first explain the problem itself.

Comment: Seems, the main problem the author is trying to solve is full code coverage. Why the class is empty is not clear but may be it is a container for some constants, etc. @Krishna, could you provide some details how do you use this class?